# Changing Direction of twist in a twisted pair (24V 4A)

Tags: noise, twisted-pair

I have two wiring harnesses one going to my power supply (24V at 5A) and the other harness going to my main board, there is a motor controller on the board so it can draw a few amps.  I noticed that the harness coming from the power supply has a left hand twist and the harness going to the main board has a right had twist so at the point when I solder the two wires together the twist will switch direction. The location of the splice is going to be near an arduino board with analog sensor lines going to it.

Is it a reasonable issue to be worried about the noise this creates?  If so it is better to retwist the harness so they go the same direction or apply some shielding over the splice joint?

Comment: There will be no noise as long as the pair is all the way kept at close proximity to each other. Twist direction is not important.

Comment: @soosaisteven. If that is an answer you gave the OP you should post it as an answer so we can vote on it and close it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no noise as long as the pair is all the way kept at close proximity to each other. The direction of the twist is not important.

Pair of wire is twisted primarily to ensure they stay as close as possible throughout their length so that their magnetic fields will cancel out.

Comment: Well, it's also so electromagnetic effects will impact both wires about equally, canceling each other out.  Telegraph (railway signal) lines and even AC power lines are also twisted "pair" - if you look closely, you will see interposition occur at certain intervals.